# Printing circle to the screen

Tags: java

Why am I not getting a circle printed to the screen when I run the following block of code? 
It doesn't print it accurately, seems like something I'm doing wrong when it's scanning the coordinates.

```
public class Question2 { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        DrawMeACircle(3, 3, 3); // should print to the screen an ellipse looking circle 
    }

    public static void DrawMeACircle(double posX, double posY, double radius) { 

        double xaxis = 20;  // scanning the coordinates
        double yaxis = 20;  // " " 

        for (double x = 0; x < xaxis; x++) { 
            for (double y = 0; y < yaxis; y++) { 

                //using the formula for a cicrle
                double a = Math.abs((posX - x) * (posX - x)); 
                double b = Math.abs((posY - y) * (posY - y)); 

                double c = Math.abs(a + b);        
                double d = Math.abs(radius * radius); 

                // checking if the formula stands correct at each coordinate scanned
                if ( c == d) {
                    System.out.print('#'); 
                } 
                else { 
                    System.out.print(' '); 
                }
            }  
            System.out.println();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: what is not working? is it not being drawn or is the printed stuff not looking like a circle?

Comment: this does seem to work but it is a crude representation of a circle since you are printing to the console

Comment: it prints an outline... but it doesnt print the '#' every where its supposed to print it. basically im tryin to get it to scan the coordinates and satisfy the equation of a circle and then print to the screen the '#' sign once the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Next time, in order to receive the best help, it is useful to describe the problem in more detail than "something is wrong". Perhaps include sample input and output. Formatting your code correctly will also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that comparing doubles like this

```
   if ( c == d) {

     System.out.print('#'); 
   }
```

is a very unreliable, they're probably missing by a little bit, and you're not printing the circle where you need to.

I'd recommend checking for a range instead

```
   double arbitraryNumber = 2;
   if ( math.abs(c - d) < arbitraryNumber)) {

     System.out.print('#'); 
   }
```

---

Or, if you want a more reliable way, I'd make a 2-d char array and treat it as a coordinate system, and then fill the 2-d array with the circle and print the array.

You can fill the array with a little bit of trigonometry.  Just figure out where the dot should be every few degrees(or radians) until you've gone 360 degrees

Comment: i tried it with int, it gives me the same result. it basically prints the outline of the circle but doesnt actually print 'hash' everywhere its supposed to.

Comment: The comparison you offer is wrong...really wrong. Probably meant `math.abs(c - d) < arbitraryNumber`

Comment: i didnt exactly get what you guys mean by that , could you explain please?

Comment: @user2997263 All you have to do is replace the first code sample Sam provides with the second code sample. Although it would be a good idea to ask your instructor why this happens as a learning exercise.

Comment: it works! thanks! i get the fact that it has to do with precision but could you explain it a little?

Comment: maybe `c` is 2.158982938 and `d` is 2.158198293.  in which case, even though they're very close, they won't match

Comment: @user2997263 The problem occurs because floating point numbers such as `double` are not real numbers. That is, they have a finite precision and so operations that are identical in math may actually produce slightly different results. For example, `0.1 / 10` produces `0.01` while `0.1 * 0.1` produces `0.010000000000000002`. See the problem?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi and you also have the fact that he's trying to pigenhole them into positions on his array

Comment: @SamIam Yes, in this case that's the big reason. Just noticed are other minor issues such as incorrect x/y loop traversal and every `Math.abs` is unnecessary.